# Remote Desktopping - 1 computer control 30

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

Is there a remote desktop solution that will allow one computer to control 30?  I have 30 student computers in a computer lab all displaying the same webpage.  I want the teacher to be able to click the log-in button, and enter her credentials once instead of needing to walk to each computer and enter it 30 times.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Not that this cant be done, but this would be a hard to accomplish.  If screen resolutions were different moving the mouse and selecting something would not work correctly

Comment: That's fine, I can make the log in process all done using the keyboard.  It's easy to change it to allow the log in to be done with the keyboard only.

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobrowsing  If you are just talking about web access.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for the suggestion.  It looks like this won't be helpful due to the log in requirements.  "Co-browsing technology has many inherent challenges such as page personalizations or sites that require user authentication."

Comment: I don't see how this would be possible. When one computer would fail at the login and another as an unexpected error... etc. what will the main computer show? The only thing you would be able to do this is some form of automation. I take it after login each student needs to control his own computer? You could send some form of AutoHotkey-sequence to login. But it would be unsafe because the student could capture this and know the password. My suggestion: change password to xx, let students login, and change the password back. Another option is opening 30 VNC session (to limit the walking ;)

Comment: Another option. You could program a special enter-page (PHP/JavaScript? or with CURL on server-side to set the cookies) which has the automation to login to that site. (also insecure but at least you could take it offline afterwards.) It would depend on the site to login to (how secure that is) how you could do this. For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999613/automatically-log-in-on-another-website-at-the-click-of-a-button-curl-or-javas) would be the simplest if the site supports it. You would need to autmate this so students can't get at the source to get the password.

Comment: @Rik I have no concern about a failed log in attempt from one of the computers.  This won't be an issue.  Also, I cannot have a script that auto logs them in since that will not be secure.

Comment: That's my point. Security. Even if you find a solution (with some mouse-automation) how would the teacher know a student hasn't opened `notepad.exe` (right after entering the website) and he's typing the password in **that**. He can't see the screens (or you would need to open 30 VNC sessions).

Comment: @Rik I'm not worried about that. The teacher can log the computers in before the children get to the lab.  I'm trying to avoid having the teacher walk to 30 computers to put in the same credentials.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11631/discussion-between-boundless-and-rik)

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how i would do it: (i have a small autologin-script for my router which i used here)

Install [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) on all the computers.

On the teachers computer create a file on the desktop named `autologin.ahk`:

```
mysite=http://192.168.178.1/logincheck.lua  ; the login site
myexpected=/home/home.lua                   ; part of the url after login
myuser=username                             ; username
mypass=password                             ; password

oIE:=ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible:=True
oIE.top:=oIE.left:=0, oIE.width:=A_ScreenWidth, oIE.height:=A_ScreenHeight
oIE.Navigate(mysite)
While oIE.readyState!=4 || oIE.document.readyState!="complete" || oIE.busy
   Sleep 50
SoundBeep

oForm:=oIE.document.getElementById("uiMainForm")    ; change this
oForm.elements.item("username").value:=myuser       ; change this
oForm.elements.item("uiPass").value:=mypass         ; change this
oForm.elements.item("uiSubmitLogin").Click()        ; change this
While oIE.readyState!=4 || oIE.document.readyState!="complete" || oIE.busy
   Sleep 50
SoundBeep

url:=oIE.LocationUrl
StringGetPos, pos, url, %myexpected%
if pos=-1
Loop
{
  Getkeystate, state, SPACE, P
  if state=D
    Break
  SoundBeep, 750, 500
  Sleep 50
}
```

You need to adjust the form-variable for your site. When the login fails it will beep and keep beeping until you press <kbd>Space</kbd>. You can test this script on the teachers computer.

Now create a `checker.ahk`:

```
script=\\teachers_computer\shared_folder\autologin.ahk
loop
{
  IfExist, %script%
  {
    run %script%
    sleep, 60000  ; 60 seconds
  }
  sleep 10000 ; 10 seconds
}
```

Run this at login of the students computers. It will check a shared folder on the teachers computer every 10 seconds if there is a `autologin.ahk`. If there is it will execute and wait for 5 minutes. (enough time for the teacher to remove the file again.)

The teacher can move the `autologin.ahk` from his desktop to the shared folder and wait until all computers are loged in (this should be within 20 seconds). Then he can move the file back to the desktop so it's no longer available to the students. When a few computers keep beeping he needs to go to these and see why the login didn't work.

No need to say that the original `autohotkey.ahk` needs to be kept secure (i take it the teachers computer **is** secure) and the file is briefly exposed when it is dropped in the shared folder (but directly removed afterwards by the teacher). As this is done before the students arrive behind their computers that shouldn't be a problem.